# xelatex stopped working after TexLive2011 update 2 days ago

Tags: xetex, errors, fontspec, texlive, polyglossia

I updated Tex Live 2011 a couple of days ago and I can't run XeLaTeX anymore on a document I was working on. When it runs it gets stuck and I have to abort it. Resulting in the following error. I've stripped the document down to the following MWE and I still get the problem. Any thoughts?

```
./Thesis
402
! Undefined control sequence.
l.402 \define@boolkey
                     {polyglossia}[xpg@]{localmarks}[false]{%
? 
Process interrupted by user
```

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, oneside]{book}

\usepackage{fontspec}                               
\setmainfont{Fontin}            
\defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
\usepackage{xunicode}
\usepackage{xltxtra}

\usepackage{polyglossia}                                
\setdefaultlanguage[variant=british]{english}                   
\usepackage{etoolbox}                               

\begin{document}

Blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Comment: Since you use xltxtra, you don't have to use explicitly fontspec and xunicode (neither graphicx). They are called from xltxtra. You should call them explicitly when you want to pass non-default options. If this is the case you should use them before xltxtra.

Comment: @pmav99: `xltxtra` is obsolete now. Just delete it. And `xunicode` is loaded by `fontspec` by default today. Then delete `xunicode`. (And `polyglossia` will load `fontspec`, of course)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Use `xkeyval` package before `polyglossia` package like this:

```
\usepackage{xkeyval}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
```

This is a bug of `polyglossia`.

**Update**

This bug has been fixed in v1.2.0b of `polyglossia`, so you should no longer need to load the `xkeyval` package manually (although doing so will cause no problems.)

Comment: https://github.com/fc7/polyglossia/issues/27#issuecomment-2125711

Comment: Note: The bug is about `xkeyval`. `fontspec` used to load `xkeyval`, but now it uses `l3keys` from LaTeX3 scheme. Some packages, like `polyglossia` and `xeCJK`, depend on `fontspec` and `xkeyval`, but don't load `xkeyval` explictly. Since `fontspec` is updated, the problem comes out. I fixed `xeCJK` in 2.4.4 some days ago; and `polyglossia` will certainly release a new version for this in days, I think.

Comment: Thanks for your clear answers. The book I was learning from was a bit out of date.