# polyglossia error after MiKTeX update

Tags: errors, xetex, polyglossia

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [xelatex stopped working after TexLive2011 update 2 days ago](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/29006/xelatex-stopped-working-after-texlive2011-update-2-days-ago)

Sorry, I don't know where I could report bug that appeared after MiKTeX Update.

Here is a test file:

```
% !Mode:: "TeX:UTF-8"
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{polyglossia}
    \setdefaultlanguage{russian}
\begin{document}
This is a test.
\end{document}
```

and log file:

```
This is XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.3-0.9997.5 (MiKTeX 2.9 64-bit) (preloaded format=xelatex 2011.9.26)  27 SEP 2011 19:14
entering extended mode
**test-l3.tex
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\Documents\My books\PlasmaBook\Test\test-l3.tex"
LaTeX2e 
Babel  and hyphenation patterns for english, french, german, italian, ru
ssian, loaded.
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\article.cls"
Document Class: article 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\size10.clo"
File: size10.clo 2007/10/19 v1.4h Standard LaTeX file (size option)
)
\c@part=\count80
\c@section=\count81
\c@subsection=\count82
\c@subsubsection=\count83
\c@paragraph=\count84
\c@subparagraph=\count85
\c@figure=\count86
\c@table=\count87
\abovecaptionskip=\skip41
\belowcaptionskip=\skip42
\bibindent=\dimen102
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\polyglossia\polyglossia.sty"
Package: polyglossia 2010/07/27 v1.2.0a Babel replacement for XeLaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\etoolbox\etoolbox.sty"
Package: etoolbox 2011/01/03 v2.1 e-TeX tools for LaTeX

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\misc\etex.sty"
Package: etex 1998/03/26 v2.0 eTeX basic definition package (PEB)
\et@xins=\count88
)
\etb@tempcnta=\count89
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\makecmds\makecmds.sty"
Package: makecmds 2009/09/03 v1.0a extra command making commands
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fon
tspec.sty"
Package: fontspec 2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/LuaLaTeX


("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\exp
l3.sty"
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3n
ames.sty"
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3b
ootstrap.sty"
Package: l3bootstrap 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental bootstrap code
)
Package: l3names 2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental namespace for primitives
) ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tools\calc.sty"
Package: calc 2007/08/22 v4.3 Infix arithmetic (KKT,FJ)
\calc@Acount=\count90
\calc@Bcount=\count91
\calc@Adimen=\dimen103
\calc@Bdimen=\dimen104
\calc@Askip=\skip43
\calc@Bskip=\skip44
LaTeX Info: Redefining \setlength on input line 76.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \addtolength on input line 77.
\calc@Ccount=\count92
\calc@Cskip=\skip45
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\color.sty"
Package: color 2005/11/14 v1.0j Standard LaTeX Color (DPC)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\color.cfg"
File: color.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 color configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package color Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 130.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xetex-def\xetex.def"
File: xetex.def 2009/11/22 v0.94 LaTeX color/graphics driver for XeTeX (RRM/JK)

))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphics.sty"
Package: graphics 2009/02/05 v1.0o Standard LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\trig.sty"
Package: trig 1999/03/16 v1.09 sin cos tan (DPC)
)
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\00miktex\graphics.cfg"
File: graphics.cfg 2007/01/18 v1.5 graphics configuration of teTeX/TeXLive
)
Package graphics Info: Driver file: xetex.def on input line 91.
)
Package: expl3 2011/09/15 v2828 L3 Experimental code bundle wrapper

("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3b
asics.sty"
Package: l3basics 2011/09/12 v2817 L3 Experimental basic definitions
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3e
xpan.sty"
Package: l3expan 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental argument expansion
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3t
l.sty"
Package: l3tl 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental token lists
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3s
eq.sty"
Package: l3seq 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental sequences and stacks
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3i
nt.sty"
Package: l3int 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental integers
\c_max_int=\count93
\l_tmpa_int=\count94
\l_tmpb_int=\count95
\l_tmpc_int=\count96
\g_tmpa_int=\count97
\g_tmpb_int=\count98
\g_seq_nesting_depth_int=\count99
\g_tl_inline_level_int=\count100
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3q
uark.sty"
Package: l3quark 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental quarks
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3p
rg.sty"
Package: l3prg 2011/09/15 v2827 L3 Experimental control structures
\g_prg_stepwise_level_int=\count101
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3c
list.sty"
Package: l3clist 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental comma separated lists
\g_clist_map_inline_int=\count102
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3t
oken.sty"
Package: l3token 2011/09/12 v2819 L3 Experimental token manipulation
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3p
rop.sty"
Package: l3prop 2011/09/12 v2820 L3 Experimental property lists
\g_prop_map_inline_int=\count103
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3m
sg.sty"
Package: l3msg 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental messages
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3i
o.sty"
Package: l3io 2011/09/10 v2799 L3 Experimental input-output operations
\l_iow_stream_int=\count104
\l_iow_line_length_int=\count105
\l_iow_target_length_int=\count106
\l_iow_current_line_int=\count107
\l_iow_current_word_int=\count108
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3f
ile.sty"
Package: l3file 2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental file operations
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3s
kip.sty"
Package: l3skip 2011/09/12 v2818 L3 Experimental dimensions and skips
\l_tmpa_dim=\dimen105
\l_tmpb_dim=\dimen106
\l_tmpc_dim=\dimen107
\g_tmpa_dim=\dimen108
\g_tmpb_dim=\dimen109
\l_tmpa_skip=\skip46
\l_tmpb_skip=\skip47
\l_tmpc_skip=\skip48
\g_tmpa_skip=\skip49
\g_tmpb_skip=\skip50
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3k
eys.sty"
Package: l3keys 2011/09/10 v2800 L3 Experimental key-value interfaces
\g_keyval_level_int=\count109
\l_keys_choice_int=\count110
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3f
p.sty"
Package: l3fp 2011/09/12 v2812 L3 Experimental floating-point operations
\c_one_million=\count111
\c_one_hundred_million=\count112
\c_five_hundred_million=\count113
\c_one_thousand_million=\count114
\c_fp_pi_by_four_decimal_int=\count115
\c_fp_pi_by_four_extended_int=\count116
\c_fp_pi_decimal_int=\count117
\c_fp_pi_extended_int=\count118
\c_fp_two_pi_decimal_int=\count119
\c_fp_two_pi_extended_int=\count120
\l_fp_count_int=\count121
\l_fp_div_offset_int=\count122
\l_fp_exp_integer_int=\count123
\l_fp_exp_decimal_int=\count124
\l_fp_exp_extended_int=\count125
\l_fp_exp_exponent_int=\count126
\l_fp_input_a_sign_int=\count127
\l_fp_input_a_integer_int=\count128
\l_fp_input_a_decimal_int=\count129
\l_fp_input_a_exponent_int=\count130
\l_fp_input_b_sign_int=\count131
\l_fp_input_b_integer_int=\count132
\l_fp_input_b_decimal_int=\count133
\l_fp_input_b_exponent_int=\count134
\l_fp_input_a_extended_int=\count135
\l_fp_input_b_extended_int=\count136
\l_fp_mul_a_i_int=\count137
\l_fp_mul_a_ii_int=\count138
\l_fp_mul_a_iii_int=\count139
\l_fp_mul_a_iv_int=\count140
\l_fp_mul_a_v_int=\count141
\l_fp_mul_a_vi_int=\count142
\l_fp_mul_b_i_int=\count143
\l_fp_mul_b_ii_int=\count144
\l_fp_mul_b_iii_int=\count145
\l_fp_mul_b_iv_int=\count146
\l_fp_mul_b_v_int=\count147
\l_fp_mul_b_vi_int=\count148
\l_fp_mul_output_int=\count149
\l_fp_output_sign_int=\count150
\l_fp_output_integer_int=\count151
\l_fp_output_decimal_int=\count152
\l_fp_output_exponent_int=\count153
\l_fp_output_extended_int=\count154
\l_fp_round_position_int=\count155
\l_fp_round_target_int=\count156
\l_fp_split_sign_int=\count157
\l_fp_tmp_int=\count158
\l_fp_trig_octant_int=\count159
\l_fp_trig_sign_int=\count160
\l_fp_trig_decimal_int=\count161
\l_fp_trig_extended_int=\count162
\l_fp_tmp_dim=\dimen110
\l_fp_tmp_skip=\skip51
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3b
ox.sty"
Package: l3box 2011/09/10 v2799 L3 Experimental boxes
\l_tmpb_box=\box26
\l_box_top_dim=\dimen111
\l_box_bottom_dim=\dimen112
\l_box_left_dim=\dimen113
\l_box_right_dim=\dimen114
\l_box_top_new_dim=\dimen115
\l_box_bottom_new_dim=\dimen116
\l_box_left_new_dim=\dimen117
\l_box_right_new_dim=\dimen118
\l_box_tmp_box=\box27
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3c
offins.sty"
Package: l3coffins 2011/09/12 v2814 L3 Experimental coffin code layer
\l_coffin_tmp_box=\box28
\l_coffin_tmp_dim=\dimen119
\l_coffin_offset_x_dim=\dimen120
\l_coffin_offset_y_dim=\dimen121
\l_coffin_x_dim=\dimen122
\l_coffin_y_dim=\dimen123
\l_coffin_x_prime_dim=\dimen124
\l_coffin_y_prime_dim=\dimen125
\l_coffin_Depth_dim=\dimen126
\l_coffin_Height_dim=\dimen127
\l_coffin_TotalHeight_dim=\dimen128
\l_coffin_Width_dim=\dimen129
\c_empty_coffin=\box29
\l_coffin_aligned_coffin=\box30
\l_coffin_aligned_internal_coffin=\box31
\l_coffin_bounding_shift_dim=\dimen130
\l_coffin_left_corner_dim=\dimen131
\l_coffin_right_corner_dim=\dimen132
\l_coffin_bottom_corner_dim=\dimen133
\l_coffin_top_corner_dim=\dimen134
\l_coffin_scaled_total_height_dim=\dimen135
\l_coffin_scaled_width_dim=\dimen136
\l_coffin_display_coffin=\box32
\l_coffin_display_coord_coffin=\box33
\l_coffin_display_pole_coffin=\box34
\l_coffin_display_offset_dim=\dimen137
\l_coffin_display_x_dim=\dimen138
\l_coffin_display_y_dim=\dimen139
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3c
olor.sty"
Package: l3color 2011/09/07 v2776 L3 Experimental colour support
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3kernel\l3l
uatex.sty"
Package: l3luatex 2011/09/10 v2798 L3 Experimental LuaTeX-specific functions
\g_cctab_allocate_int=\count163
\g_cctab_stack_int=\count164
))
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\l3packages\x
parse\xparse.sty"
Package: xparse 2011/09/15 v2828 L3 Experimental document command parser
\l_xparse_m_args_int=\count165
\l_xparse_mandatory_args_int=\count166
\l_xparse_processor_int=\count167
\l_xparse_total_args_int=\count168
)
\l_fontspec_script_int=\count169
\l_fontspec_language_int=\count170
\l_fontspec_strnum_int=\count171
\l_fontspec_tmpa_dim=\dimen140
\l_fontspec_tmpb_dim=\dimen141
\l_fontspec_tmpc_dim=\dimen142
Variant \tl_gset:cV already defined; not changing it on line 66

("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fon
tspec-patches.sty"
Package: fontspec-patches 2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/
LuaLaTeX
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fixltx2e.sty"
Package: fixltx2e 2006/09/13 v1.1m fixes to LaTeX
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 420.
)
LaTeX Info: Redefining \em on input line 22.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \emph on input line 29.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \- on input line 32.
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \liningnums with arg. spec. 'm' on line 111.
.................................................
)
("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fon
tspec-xetex.sty"
Package: fontspec-xetex 2011/09/18 v2.2a Advanced font selection for XeLaTeX/Lu
aLaTeX
 ("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\base\fontenc.sty"
Package: fontenc 2005/09/27 v1.99g Standard LaTeX package

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1enc.def"
File: eu1enc.def 2010/05/27 v0.1h Experimental Unicode font encodings
)
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmr on input line 100.


("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmr.fd"
File: eu1lmr.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\xelatex\xunicode\xunicode.sty"
File: xunicode.sty 2011/09/09 v0.981 provides access to latin accents and many 
other characters in Unicode lower plane

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\tipa\t3enc.def"
File: t3enc.def 2001/12/31 T3 encoding
LaTeX Font Info:    Try loading font information for EU1+lmss on input line 357
.

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\euenc\eu1lmss.fd"
File: eu1lmss.fd 2009/10/30 v1.6 Font defs for Latin Modern
))
\tipaTiiicode=\count172
\tipasavetokens=\toks14
\tipachecktokens=\toks15

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\graphicx.sty"
Package: graphicx 1999/02/16 v1.0f Enhanced LaTeX Graphics (DPC,SPQR)

("C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\tex\latex\graphics\keyval.sty"
Package: keyval 1999/03/16 v1.13 key=value parser (DPC)
\KV@toks@=\toks16
)
\Gin@req@height=\dimen143
\Gin@req@width=\dimen144
))
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \fontspec with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 39.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmainfont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 43.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setsansfont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 47.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmonofont with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 51.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathrm with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 59.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setboldmathrm with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 62.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathsf with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 65.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \setmathtt with arg. spec. 'O{}m' on line 68.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontfamily with arg. spec. 'mO{}m' on line 84.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontface with arg. spec. 'mO{}m' on line 87.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \defaultfontfeatures with arg. spec. 'm' on line
. 91.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \addfontfeatures with arg. spec. 'm' on line 107.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 118.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newAATfeature with arg. spec. 'mmmm' on line 125.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newICUfeature with arg. spec. 'mmm' on line 132.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \aliasfontfeature with arg. spec. 'mm' on line
. 159.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \aliasfontfeatureoption with arg. spec. 'mmm' on
. line 164.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontscript with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 169.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \newfontlanguage with arg. spec. 'mm' on line 192.
.................................................
.................................................
. xparse info: "define-command"
. 
. Defining document command \DeclareFontsExtensions with arg. spec. 'm' on
. line 211.
.................................................
Variant \prop_gput:cnV already defined; not changing it on line 485
Variant \prop_gput:cnx already defined; not changing it on line 486
Variant \keys_set:nx already defined; not changing it on line 963
\c@fontspec_tmp_int=\count173
LaTeX Info: Redefining \itshape on input line 1881.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \slshape on input line 1885.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \scshape on input line 1889.
LaTeX Info: Redefining \upshape on input line 1893.

("C:\Users\Igor A. Kotelnikov\AppData\Roaming\MiKTeX\2.9\tex\latex\fontspec\fon
tspec.cfg")))
! Undefined control sequence.
l.402 \define@boolkey
                     {polyglossia}[xpg@]{localmarks}[false]{%
? e

Here is how much of TeX's memory you used:
 13320 strings out of 430245
 287236 string characters out of 3188361
 282049 words of memory out of 3000000
 16409 multiletter control sequences out of 15000+200000
 3680 words of font info for 19 fonts, out of 3000000 for 9000
 198 hyphenation exceptions out of 8191
 50i,0n,31p,830b,95s stack positions out of 5000i,500n,10000p,200000b,50000s
No pages of output.
```

I updated the following 4 packages: `fontspec` (packaged on 2011-09-19), `l3kernel` (2011-09-16) and `l3packages` (2011-09-16) alhough XeLaTeX compiler reports that error resides in `polyglossia.sty`.

Fortunately, I have saved onto my local drive the following version of these packages, which do work: `fontspec` (2011-02-28), `l3kernel` (2011-08-19) and `l3packages` (2011-08-19).

Comment: This is a duplicate: `polyglossia` was relying on `fontspec` to load `xkeyval`.

Comment: And the bug in `polyglossia` has now been fixed, as of version 1.2.0b.